# Variable name to include value of another variable

Tags: variables, lua

Lets say I have pre-defined 3 variables, `x1`, `x2`, and `x3`, each of which is a different co-ordinate on the screen. I have a whole chunk of code to decide whether another variable, `a` will equal `1`, `2`, or `3`. Now, I want to include the value of a in a variable name, allowing me to 'dynamically' change between `x1`, `x2`, and `x3`.

E.g. `a` is set to `2`. Now I want to move the mouse to `xa`, so if `a=2`, `xa` is `x2`, which is a predefined variable.

Its probably clear I am very new to Lua, I have tried googling the issue, but I'm not really sure what I am looking for, terminology wise and such.

Anyhow, is anyone able to help me out?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you can change the code where `x1`, `x2` and `x3` are defined, a cleaner approach is to use arrays (i.e. array-like tables). This is the general approach when you need a sequence of variables indexed by a number.

Therefore, instead of `x1`, `x2` and `x3` you could define:

```
local x = {}
x[1] = 10  -- instead of x1
x[2] = 20  -- instead of x2
x[3] = 30  -- instead of x3
```

Now instead of using `xa` you simply use `x[a]`.

Answer (score 5):

If `xa` are global variables, you can use the table `_G` like this:

```
x1 = 42   
x2 = 43
x3 = 44 

local a = 2
print(_G['x' .. a])
```

Output:

```
43
```